# Xcode: best way to create a user login and a place that can hold an array associated to their login

Tags: mysql, arrays, xcode, authentication, account

I'm looking for some help. I am about to delve into something I am relative new to. I am am trying to create a system for my app where a user can create an account and login and once they have done so it uploads an array to a database so that the array can be retrieved by other users.

I understand that this is kind of complicated, but I'm sure somebody has experienced this issue before. I have read about mysql but I'm not sure if when the user creates an account, that I can upload the array and it can be accessed by other contacts.

If someone could give me links to tutorials that you found helpful then it would be greatly appreciated.

Pseudo code would be:
User 1 creates account.
User 1 logs in.
App uploads array to users account stored online.
When user 2 logs in (assuming he has created an account)
He adds the first user as a contact of app.
He downloads the array of user 1 and uploads his array

Comment: What part do you find complicated creating the login or uploading and downloading the array? What server side language are you using PHP or something else?

mysql is a relational database. Think of columns as variables and rows as observations. You can insert the elements of your array and again retrieve the elements and place them in an array.

Outline at least pseudo code to get more specific help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The part I find complicated is assigning an array to an account. I added the pseudo code above :)

Comment: You need to create a schema for the table in your database.   There are two ways you could do this.  You can either have a wide table or a narrow table.  The wide table would have the user id and then each element of the array as a column.  This method works best if you have a fixed length array.  The more standard approach is to have a narrow table with two columns.  The first column is the user id and the second column is the array element.  Each row holds 1 element of the array

Comment: So the problem is that I have an array that has varying length. I'm stupid because there is no way that I can alter the table's rows/columns from my app.